# How to change color of the drives' used space in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, desktop-customization

The default in Windows 7 is blue and red. How do I change those colors to something like gray and black to match my custom theme?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it is certainly possible, as the [desktop modders on DeviantART](http://alkhan.deviantart.com/art/New-Theme-For-Windows-7-124567618) have been doing it.

I would think that will need to use Resource Hacker (last beta version for x64) or similar resource editor, like [XN Resource Editor](http://www.wilsonc.demon.co.uk/d10resourceeditor.htm) and open shellstyle.dll.  The bitmap that you will need to replace will be in there somewhere.

Comment: Back in 2001, I was so appalled by the Luna theme in XP that I made my own. It was very simplistic, but later on I just used a self-modified version of the Royal Noir theme, with thin window title bars.

Answer (score -2):

Yes,  You can change the color from disk management. Right click on computer click on manage a new window computer management will pop up. On top click on VIEW tab then click on settings. Now can change the color according to your theme.

Comment: He's talking about the colour of the bars in Computer, not in Disk Management.